# Trying to install director using pip and other methods in python aren't working. How am I able to add this?

Tags: python, module, libraries

This is the error I keep getting:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install director
Collecting director
  Using cached director-1.2.0.tar.gz (96 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zg680y8j\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zg680y8j\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zg680y8j\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zg680y8j\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 79
          except Exception, ex:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried to install using pip in cmd, installing it by importing it and the IDE recognizing that it isn't installed, also going into project properties to import it. Every option seems to fail.

Comment: *"This library is no longer under active development."*

Comment: according to the [pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/director/) this looks like an retired package (last released: 2009 and retired on March 1st, 2017.)....